# Wordpress, Manually Adding like button for Comments reply

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

i would like to know how can i insert this code in Comments form for the reply section.

```
echo get_simple_likes_button( get_comment_ID(), 1 );
```

I really tried more time to do it but i fail, i feel the template is very complicated,

this is the comment template

```
if ( have_comments() ) : ?>
    <h3 class="comments-title">
        <?php
            $comments_number = get_comments_number();
            if ( '1' === $comments_number ) {
                /* translators: %s: post title */
                printf( esc_html( _x( 'One Comment on &ldquo;%s&rdquo;', 'comments title', 'hitmag' ) ), get_the_title() );
            } else {
                printf(
                    /* translators: 1: number of comments, 2: post title */
                    esc_html(
                        _nx(
                            '%1$s Comment on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;',
                            '%1$s Comments on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;',
                            $comments_number,
                            'comments title',
                            'hitmag'
                        )
                    ),
                    number_format_i18n( $comments_number ),
                    get_the_title()
                );
            }
        ?>

    </h3><!-- .comments-title -->

    <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // Are there comments to navigate through? ?>
    <nav id="comment-nav-above" class="navigation comment-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h2 class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comment navigation', 'hitmag' ); ?></h2>
        <div class="nav-links">

            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Older Comments', 'hitmag' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Newer Comments', 'hitmag' ) ); ?></div>

        </div><!-- .nav-links -->
    </nav><!-- #comment-nav-above -->
    <?php endif; // Check for comment navigation. ?>

    <ol class="comment-list">
        <?php
            wp_list_comments( array(
                'style'         => 'ol',
                'short_ping'    => true,
                'avatar_size'   => 50,
            ) );
        ?>
    </ol><!-- .comment-list -->
```

this is the second part of the template, i can't figure it out where is the reply parts in this template

```
<?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : // Are there comments to navigate through? ?>
    <nav id="comment-nav-below" class="navigation comment-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h2 class="screen-reader-text"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comment navigation', 'hitmag' ); ?></h2>
        <div class="nav-links">

            <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Older Comments', 'hitmag' ) ); ?></div>
            <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( esc_html__( 'Newer Comments', 'hitmag' ) ); ?></div>

        </div><!-- .nav-links -->
    </nav><!-- #comment-nav-below -->
    <?php
    endif; // Check for comment navigation.

endif; // Check for have_comments().


// If comments are closed and there are comments, let's leave a little note, shall we?
if ( ! comments_open() && get_comments_number() && post_type_supports( get_post_type(), 'comments' ) ) : ?>

    <p class="no-comments"><?php esc_html_e( 'Comments are closed.', 'hitmag' ); ?></p>
<?php
endif;

comment_form();
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can not help you with the information you present. Add more details to your question.

Comment: Hello Dear Philipp, I tried to add my comments template with my question but i can't :( and i need just hint with key word for searching.

Comment: Or if there is any functionality to add it, tell me please. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It would be because you're "echo"ing a PHP function, which is a "no no". Remove the `echo` and place it where you did before, cause I am assuming since you said "comment" form, you know where it is...

Comment: i can't figure it out where is the reply parts in this template? :(

Comment: Why is `echo`ing a php function a "no no"?

Comment: it's "no no" if you don't know what it's returning. In your case I think you're taking it from a plugin (https://github.com/JonMasterson/WordPress-Post-Like-System). From their instructions, you're doing it right. But I don't understand why you want to place it in the comments section because it logs "like" on current post not on the comments?.

Comment: The comments section has a conditional to display if it has/does not have comments, which is unrelated to whether a user likes the post or not, which is what that function is for. Place your code inside the loop on the single.php and use css to position it where you want according to generated html (use chrome console ). It would serve you better.

Comment: Thanks Marshall for support.

Comment: Hi, Marshall, it's better to answer questions after they are clarified by the OP. I removed the comments you made on your answer... this kind of thing must be done using the comment section below the question. But you need to achieve 50 points first to be able to comment in any question. Good luck and welcome to [so]!